# How do I ssh from school computer to home computer?

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, ssh-tunneling

I can ssh from my home linux to school by typing

```
ssh <school id>@<school>.ca
```

but what if I want to do it the other way around?

I am at school and I want to connect to my home computer. How do I do this?

Suppose my username on my home computer is bob. How do I proceed from here? using putty/terminal?

I tried doing:

```
ssh bob@<public ip of home network found using whatsmyip>
```

but this didn't work.

I am sure my home has internet connection.

Comment: You will likely need to forward port 22 from your home router to your linux terminal.

Comment: @Jesse_b after doing a bit more reading I believe that may be the issue

Comment: But am I connecting properly (proper syntax)?

Comment: In addition to opening port 22, you need to install ssh daemon on your home PC so that the daemon can bind to that port and listen for your connection.. One caveat: I highly recommend using key-pairs for this so you dont become as vulnerable and also disable root login

Comment: Yes that is the correct syntax.  Your linux machine likely already has openssh installed but you can check with `ssh -V` or `sshd -V` .

Comment: @Jesse_b yes it does, I can connect locally from pc to pc in my home

Comment: If you have multiple terminals on your home network that you need to connect to you can likely accomplish that fairly easily with port forwarding as well.  Say you have: `terminal 1: 10.10.10.101` `terminal 2: 10.10.10.102` and `terminal 3: 10.10.10.103` and your external IP is `15.15.15.15` you can setup your port forwarding like: `source port 22 -> 10.10.10.101 dest port 22` `source port 23 -> 10.10.10.102 dest port 22` etc that way you can just ssh to your external IP on a different port for each machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to public_ip:port, you are actually connecting to the router but since (most likely) your host is behind the NAT created by the router itself, you need to forward the connection to internal_ip:port.

Typically you can do this from the router's web page under the port forwarding section.

Be aware that this allows anyone to connect from anywhere, so make sure you are using ssh keys to login and prevent bruteforce via tools like failtoban or ufw/iptables.

Comment: But even if I use public_ip:port, wont it still ask for password? I don't see the major issue?

Comment: Yes but passwords are easier to bruteforce. Also you can use the same key to log into multiple servers.

Comment: Matteo answered the question, but just to add: if you use a router like pfSense you can set it to only allow SSH traffic from a certain IP or a range of IP's, etc. I have mine setup like this so I can RDP into my home PC from work, but not from anywhere else (since opening port 3389 for RDP to the entire internet is very insecure).